# Rails nested resource is showing up twice.. once at the start and once at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource called a ClinicalCase which has_many questions (nested resource). The premise is to show a case all the time, and be able to see one question at a time. My issue is that, if a case has 5 questions, the app is only showing 4. It will show the same question for the first array index and last array index, and everything in between will be the same.

For example, if case 1 has questions "foo", "bar" and "baz", "foo" and "bar" will only show up, with "foo" at the start and the end. I have no idea why this is happening.

I'm using will_paginate to assist with the pagination, as each user needs to see one case at a time, and one question at a time that belongs to the case.

Here's my code (working fine, except that the first and last question of a case show up as the exact same)

**controller**

```
  def tagged
    @cases = ClinicalCase.with_tag(params[:tag]).paginate(:page => params[:case], :per_page => 1)
  end
```

**model**

```
class ClinicalCase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :clinical_case
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  acts_as_taggable

  scope :with_tag,      -> (tag) { tagged_with(tag) if tag.present? }

  def paginated_questions(page, per_page = 1)
    questions.paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page)
  end
```

**view part 1: tagged.html.erb**

```
<% @cases.each do |clin_case| %>

  <%= render "clinical_cases/question", clin_case: clin_case, questions: clin_case.questions %>

  <%= will_paginate @cases, :param_name => 'case', :previous_label => 'Previous Case', :next_label => 'Next Case', :page_links => false %><br>

<% end %>
```

**view part 2: _question.html.erb**

```
<% questions = clin_case.paginated_questions(params[:page]) %>
  <% questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= question.title %>

      <% question.answers.shuffle.each do |x| %>
        <% if x.correct? %>
          <%= x.choice %>
            <% else %>
          <%= x.choice %>
            <% end %>
      <% end %>

  <%= will_paginate questions, :previous_label => 'Prev. Ques.', :next_label => 'Next Question', :page_links => false %>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and I'm not sure why it started working but it did.

```
<% @questions = clin_case.questions.order("created_at ASC").paginate(:page => params[:question], :per_page => 1) %>

<%= render @questions %>
```

I used the local variable to get the association and added an order method in ASC, and that caused it to work.